# How do I correctly use 'styled-components'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I created a spinner for my application. It works in every way as intended. I am, however, getting a warning stating that I am using "Styled" in the wrong manner. I Attempted to convert the component into a class based component, but it did not work. I am 100% positive this is not the best way to create this component, but I am relatively new to React. The reason I am even using Styled-components is because of the ":after" being unavailable in JSX inline styling. I would be tremendously thankful for any advice anyone may have regarding this issue. I would assume there is a relatively simple solution to this, but I have not found it.

> The component styled.div with the id of "sc-bdnylx" has been created dynamically.
> You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
> To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.

I call my Spinner with:

```
<Spinner additionalclasses='mr20' size='small' color='#39FF14' />
```

The code for the Spinner component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './spinner.css'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function Spinner(props) {
let wrapperStyles = {}
let spinnerStyles = {}

switch (props.size) {
    case 'extrasmall':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '20px', height: '20px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(-38%) scale(0.25)` }
        break
    case 'small':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '40px', height: '40px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(-25%) scale(0.5)` }
        break
    case 'medium':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '60px', height: '60px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(-12.5%) scale(0.75)` }
        break
    case 'large':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '80px', height: '80px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(-0%) scale(1)` }
        break
    case 'extralarge':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '120px', height: '120px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(25%) scale(1.5)` }
        break
    case 'huge':
        wrapperStyles = { width: '240px', height: '240px' }
        spinnerStyles = { transform: `translateX(94%) scale(3)` }
        break
    default:
        wrapperStyles = {}
        spinnerStyles = {}
}

let color = props.color

const SpinnerDiv = styled.div`
    &:after {
        background: ${color};
    }
`

return (
    <div
        className={`spinner_wrapper ${props.additionalclasses}`}
        style={wrapperStyles}
    >
        <div className='spinner_container' style={spinnerStyles}>
            <div className='lds-spinner' style={{ color: `${color}` }}>
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
                <SpinnerDiv />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Spinner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to move the `SpinnerDiv` styled component outside your functional component because it is being re-created everytime your component re-renders.

And inside your render function you can pass props to the `styled-component` as you wanted to, like this:

```
<SpinnerDiv color={/* a color */} />
```

And then to use it in the styled component:

```
const SpinnerDiv = styled.div`
    &:after {
        background: ${props => props.color};
    }
`;
```

Or even better, you can destructure `props`:

```
const SpinnerDiv = styled.div`
    &:after {
        background: ${({ color }) => color};
    }
`;
```